# Why doesn't the QPrinterDialog take the default options of each printer correctly in PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyside

I am trying to get a PrinterDialog for users to choose all the options for printing.

When I try this with PySide, the returned printer is always the same (default I guess), no matter what changes the user makes in the dialog. The same happens when I pass it a printer initially.

I have come up with this small self-contained example to see what I am talking about.

```
USE_PYQT4 = True

if USE_PYQT4:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
else:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

import sys

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.printBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Print Preview")
        self.printBtn.clicked.connect(self.onPrint)

        # Will store the QPrinter instance
        self.printer = None
        # Will store the QPrintDialog, because it
        # might get garbage-collected, and the QPrinter with it
        self.pdialog = None

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.printBtn)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def printState(self):
        print '*'*20
        if self.printer is None:
            print '-- no printer -- '
        else:
            print 'printer name', self.printer.printerName()
            print 'page size', self.printer.pageSize()
            print 'paper size', self.printer.paperSize()
        print
        print

    def askPrinter(self):
        # Either like this:
        # 
        # self.printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
        # self.pdialog = dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog(self.printer)

        # Or like that:
        # 
        self.pdialog = dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog()

        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintCollateCopies, True)
        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintCurrentPage, True)
        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintPageRange, True)
        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintSelection, True)
        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintShowPageSize, True)
        dialog.setOption(QtGui.QAbstractPrintDialog.PrintToFile, True)

        print 'before PrintDialog'
        self.printState()

        if dialog.exec_() != QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            return False

        # And that, if not set before
        self.printer = dialog.printer()

        print 'after PrintDialog'
        self.printState()

        return True

    def onPrint(self):
        if not self.askPrinter():
            print 'oops'
            return

        self.preview()

    def preview(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer)
        dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
        dialog.exec_()

    def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
        doc = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(doc)

        cursor.insertText("""
        SOME TEXT
        """)
        cursor.insertText("-"*20)

        data = [('Line {}'.format(i), '{} times'.format(i*2)) for i in xrange(20)]

        table = cursor.insertTable(len(data), max(len(d) for d in data))        
        for row in range(table.rows()):
            for column in range(table.columns()):
                cursor.insertText(unicode(data[row][column]))
                cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)

        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextBlock)

        cursor.insertText("-"*20)
        cursor.insertText("""
        And that's it
        """)

        doc.print_(printer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.window = Window()
    app.window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that when using PyQt4, the issue is different:

In PySide, if the page size is not set manually, it takes `A4` (maybe it's the default for the first printer). Also, the options set from `setOption` seem to be ignored...

In PyQt4, the page size is set to `0`, whatever that is, unless the page size dialog is opened. When the page size is `0`, it's definitely different than when the page size dialog is opened. Also, the page margins are set to 0 here. However, the options are respected and it takes the correct default values (set through the CUPS admin page).

What is weird is that I checked the Kate print dialog, and it's completely correct. Kate is a Qt application in C++. I couldn't test that myself on C++ though.

- Is this the correct way to create a QPrintDialog or am I doing something wrong?
- Why is there that much difference? Shouldn't it all be delegated to Qt in the end?
- How can I overcome this difference? (i.e. by manually taking the differences and filling the values or something)

I'm on Python 2.7.3 with PySide 1.1.0 and PyQt4 4.10.1 on Linux.

Thanks in advance for any input.

**Update**:

I tried the [example](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/blobs/master/examples/richtext/orderform.py) provided with PySide, and it has the same issues; so most probably I'm not doing anything wrong.

Also, I checked bug reports. There are lots of them, none of which lead to anywhere. Some are fixed for Qt5, some ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your piece of code. It works perfectly and returns the correct printer and page setup. on win xp, PySide 1.1.2 and python 3.3.2. it may be a problem with your qt libraries or some os mis-configurations.

Comment: The issue is only with the Linux dialog. On Windows, it works perfectly fine because it does not use the same dialog (it uses Windows' dialog, not Qt's).